# JAVA: Knowing the Method/Class from where a static method was called

Tags: java

I would like to know if there's a way in java to find out the class/object that called a certain static method.

Example:

```
public class Util{
 ...
 public static void method(){}
 ...
}

public class Caller{
 ...
 public void callStatic(){
   Util.method();
 }
 ...
}
```

Can I find out if `Util.method` was called from the `Caller` class?

Comment: Class names should start with an uppercase letter :)

Comment: I don't know where I got the lowercase habit (probably actionscript) :) I'm using uppercase naming @work, but my mind is set on lower.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()` in `Util.method`.

To get the last call before `Util.method` you can do something like this:

```
public class Util {
 ...
 public static void method() {
    StackTraceElement[] st = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
    //st[0] is the call of getStackTrace, st[1] is the call to Util.method, so the method before is st[2]
    System.out.println(st[2].getClassName() + "." + st[2].getMethodName());
 }
 ...
}
```

Comment: I think the asker wants more than the class name and method, the object itself.

Comment: If he wants that, he didn't really asked that way :)

Comment: My formulation of the question may have been faulted, yes. This is what I actually wanted. Is there a way to know the specific objectm though? :)